# percentage of range of colors in image

Tags: python

I am trying to determine the percentage of color in images

```
def get_domn(path):
    im = Image.open(path)
    t=max(im.getcolors(im.size[0]*im.size[1])) #get the dominant color
```

this return a tuple of size,color(r,g,b) what I want to do is find the sizes of r+1,r+2,r+3,r+4,r+5,r-1,r-2,r-3,r-4,r-5,g+1 ... i.e +-5 for each r,g,b so I can determine the color+-=5 size percentage out of the original image size

```
s=0
for i in im.getcolors(im.size[0]*im.size[1]):
    s+=i[0] 
#s will be the size of image
```

this is what I am doing to achieve this but I believe there is a more Pythonic way of doing (C background)

```
t=max(im.getcolors(im.size[0]*im.size[1]))
y=[t[1]]
for i in range(5):
   r=t[1][0]+i
   y.append((r,t[1][1],t[1][2]))

for i in range(5):
   r=t[1][0]-i
   y.append((r,t[1][1],t[1][2]))
```

...  and so on for green,blue

Comment: Sorry, so your attempt does work, you're just looking for the Pythonic way? Also, maybe I am reading it incorrectly, but is _determine the color+=5 size percentage_  supposed to be _determine the **color+-5** size percentage_?

Comment: @ChrismonChin I fixed it sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any extra libraries you can do

```
y=[t[1]]
for i in range(1,5):
    r1=t[1][0]+i
    r2=t[1][0]-i
    g1=t[1][0]+i
    g2=t[1][0]-i
    b1=t[1][0]+i
    b2=t[1][0]-i
    y.append((r1,t[1][1],t[1][2]))
    y.append((r2,t[1][1],t[1][2]))
    y.append((t[1][0],g1,t[1][2]))
    y.append((t[1][0],g2,t[1][2]))
    y.append((t[1][0],t[1][1],b1))
    y.append((t[1][0],t[1][1],b2))
s=0
for i in im.getcolors(im.size[0]*im.size[1]):
    if i[1] in y:
        s+=i[0]
clr_percentage = s*100/(im.size[0]*im.size[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't completely understand the question, here is a three line solution to what I understand in the code. For all 3 colours.

```
y += [(x, t[1][1], t[1][2]) for x in [t[1][0] + i for i in range(-5, 6)]]
y += [(t[1][0], x, t[1][2]) for x in [t[1][1] + i for i in range(-5, 6) if i != 0]]
y += [(t[1][0], t[1][1], x) for x in [t[1][2] + i for i in range(-5, 6) if i != 0]]
```

Now this includes +-5 while yours is +-4, I did 5 as thats what I understood, but change it to `range(-4,5)` if not